# AWS CodeBuild pushing git tag to remote causes `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

Tags: git, github

**Background:**

I have an AWS CodeBuild project used for testing a Github repo. If all the tests pass, the build creates a new remote tag via [semtag](https://github.com/nico2sh/semtag) based on the master branch. The Codebuild project has a personal access token used for Github authentication.

Here's the Codebuild buildspec.yaml file:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  shell: bash
  git-credential-helper: yes
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - pre-commit install
    on-failure: ABORT
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pre-commit run --all-files
    on-failure: ABORT
  post_build: 
    commands:
      - "echo Source Version: ${CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION}"
      - "echo Source Repo URL: ${CODEBUILD_SOURCE_REPO_URL}"
      - |
        git remote -v

        if [ $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION = "master" ]; then
          git-chglog -o CHANGELOG.md `semtag getfinal` `semtag final -s minor -f -o`;
          semtag final -s minor -f;
        fi
```

**Problem:**

When the build tries to push the tag to the remote repo via the command: `semtag final -s minor -f`, this error arises:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
Error pushing the tag v0.3.0 to origin
```

The output of the `git remote -v` is:

```
origin  https://github.com/<username>/<repo> (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<username>/<repo> (push)
```

**Attempts:**

All attempts below have previous commands that get the relevant `GITHUB_*` vars

1.

```
git config remote.origin.url https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_USERNAME}/${GITHUB_REPO}.git
git remote -v

if [ $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION = "master" ]; then
  git-chglog -o CHANGELOG.md `semtag getfinal` `semtag final -s minor -f -o`;
  semtag final -s minor -f;
fi
```

outputs:

```
origin  https://"***"@github.com/marshall7m/terraform-aws-github-ci.git (fetch)
origin  https://"***"@github.com/marshall7m/terraform-aws-github-ci.git (push)

fatal: could not read Password for 'https://"***"@github.com': No such device or address
Error pushing the tag v0.3.0 to origin
```

2. 

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_USERNAME}/${GITHUB_REPO}.git
git remote -v

if [ $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION = "master" ]; then
  git-chglog -o CHANGELOG.md `semtag getfinal` `semtag final -s minor -f -o`;
  semtag final -s minor -f;
fi
```

outputs:

```
origin  https://"***"@github.com/marshall7m/terraform-aws-github-ci.git (fetch)
origin  https://"***"@github.com/marshall7m/terraform-aws-github-ci.git (push)

fatal: could not read Password for 'https://"***"@github.com': No such device or address
Error pushing the tag v0.3.0 to origin
```

3. 

```
git remote set-url origin https://${GITHUB_USERNAME}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_USERNAME}/${GITHUB_REPO}.git
git remote -v

if [ $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION = "master" ]; then
  git-chglog -o CHANGELOG.md `semtag getfinal` `semtag final -s minor -f -o`;
  semtag final -s minor -f;
fi
```

outputs:

```
origin  https://marshall7m:"***"@github.com/marshall7m/terraform-aws-github-ci.git (fetch)
origin  https://marshall7m:"***"@github.com/marshall7m/terraform-aws-github-ci.git (push)

remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://marshall7m:"***"@github.com/marshall7m/terraform-aws-github-ci.git/'
Error pushing the tag v0.3.0 to origin
```

Comment: Did you give your token access to your repo, and access to push to it?

Comment: Yes I did, I used the`public_repo` scope. Currently trying to see if giving `repo` access helps

Comment: No luck with `repo` scope

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by setting the "git-credential-helper" variable in my `buildspec.yml` file like

```yaml
env:
  git-credential-helper: yes
```

and setting the username in the git config like

```bash
git config --global user.email "<>"
git config --global user.name "AWS CodeBuild"
```